# Integrate Hibernate into a new Spring MVC Project (generated by STS)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm new to the Spring world - and just installed STS (Spring Tool Suite), and successfully created, configured, and deployed a SpringMVC on my local machine thanks to this helpful blog post:

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide

I was wondering if anyone had any documentation or resources that expands upon this and provides some insight on how to integrate Hibernate into a project like this?  I'm new to Hibernate as well - would that be the best solution?  Or is there something better out there?  Appreciate the help!

Comment: for example Spring.io getting started tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/  (but it is based on spring-boot so you will not learn so much about spring)

Answer (score 0):

Check github.  There are zillions of examples.  e.g. https://github.com/heroku/template-java-spring-hibernate.  Happy coding.